# How to use smartphone LCD on computer?

Tags: lcd

Smartphone's LCD are small and tactile, perfect in size to integrate them on your computer case for monitoring purpose.

I searched for LVDS to DVI/HDMI but i'm not even sure the input is LVDS and every board i found had different connector for the LVDS side, it was never the same connector the smartphone's LCD has.

I don't know what is required to get the touchscreen input at all.

What information should i search, LCD + touchscreen side, and what's the hardware name required for this ?

Do you have a better solution than using a smartphone LCD ? Maybe there is small displays with touchscreen input and good resolution available with more common connectors ? (didn't found any, size around 5")

Comment: You might look into buying LCDs meant specifically to integrate with PCs, such as from http://www.crystalfontz.com/ as an example.

Comment: That still doesn't help me to understand what should I look for to know what board to use to connect it to the computer.

Answer (score 0):

you can't integrate directly to you'r motherboard it wouldn't have any interfacing IC, Without the interface we can't give input to motherboard or output from mother board, you can do one thing you can create some drivers for you'r LCD and connect it using USB.

Comment: I don't think I asked how to connect it to the motherboard directly, was more asking "what should I search to use it" I don't have the skills to make my own driver for this.